# iOS Swift TableviewCell issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a strange problem with tableView cell.

when I scroll tableView and cell disappear and back again to the cell I understand that tableView add similar cell exactly on cell.

for example look at the picture . 3 exact text add on each other.

[image]

cellForRowAtIndexPath **function** :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let reviewNumber = UILabel()

        if (self.book.review_count == 0) {
            reviewNumber.text = "\(self.lang.book["no_review"]!)"
        }
        if (self.book.review_count > 0) {
            reviewNumber.text = "\(self.book.review_count!) \(self.lang.general["review"]!)"
        }

        reviewNumber.textAlignment = .Right
        reviewNumber.font = UIFont(name: "Vazir", size: 14)
        reviewNumber.numberOfLines = 0
        reviewNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        reviewNumber.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        cell.contentView.addSubview(reviewNumber)




        let voteIcon = UIImageView()
        voteIcon.image = UIImage(named: "vote-icn")
        voteIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(voteIcon)
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[v0(24)]-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : voteIcon]))


        let reviewIcon = UIImageView()
        reviewIcon.image = UIImage(named: "review-icn")
        reviewIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(reviewIcon)
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[v0(24)]-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : reviewIcon]))


        let voteNumber = UILabel()
        voteNumber.text = " ۴.۵ از ۱۶۵۴رأی"
        voteNumber.textAlignment = .Left
        voteNumber.font = UIFont(name: "Vazir", size: 14)
        voteNumber.numberOfLines = 0
        voteNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        voteNumber.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        cell.contentView.addSubview(voteNumber)


        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-3-[v0]-3-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : reviewNumber]))
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-3-[v0]-3-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : voteNumber]))
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-35-[v0]-8-[v1(25)]",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : voteNumber, "v1" : voteIcon, "v2" : reviewNumber, "v3" : reviewIcon]))

        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[v2]-8-[v3(25)]-35-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : voteNumber, "v1" : voteIcon, "v2" : reviewNumber, "v3" : reviewIcon]))



    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {

        let userBookStatusButtn = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        userBookStatusButtn.setTitle("خواهم خواند", forState: .Normal)
        userBookStatusButtn.alpha = 0.2
        userBookStatusButtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Vazir", size: 14)
        userBookStatusButtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        //            userBookStatusButtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "vote-icn"), forState: .Normal)
        userBookStatusButtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        userBookStatusButtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.0/256.0 ,green:150.0/256.0, blue:136.0/256.0 ,alpha:1 )

        cell.contentView.addSubview(userBookStatusButtn)

        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[v0(48)]-20-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : userBookStatusButtn]))
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-35-[v0]-35-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : userBookStatusButtn]))


    }

    if indexPath.row == 2 {

        let topBorder = UIView()
        topBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(topBorder)

        let bottomBorder = UIView()
        bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(bottomBorder)


        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
        paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .RightToLeft

        guard let descriptionStr = self.book.description else {return cell}
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: descriptionStr)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))


        let description = UILabel()
        description.attributedText = attrString
        description.textAlignment = .Justified
        description.font = UIFont(name: "Vazir", size: 14)
        description.numberOfLines = 0
        description.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        description.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        cell.contentView.addSubview(description)



        let title = UILabel()
        title.text = "\(self.lang.book["summery"]!)"
        title.alpha = 0.2
        title.textAlignment = .Center
        title.font = UIFont(name: "Vazir-Bold", size: 16)
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(title)



        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[v0]-|",options: [.AlignAllCenterX],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : title]))
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[v0]-20-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : description]))

        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[v1]-44-[v0]",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : description,"v1" : title ]))
        cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v0]-8-|",options: [],metrics: nil,views: ["v0" : description,"v1" : title ]))



    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = nil



    return cell

}
```

I get data from son file with **Alamofire** and reloadData :

```
func tableRefresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.bookDetailTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

what's my problem?

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a classical error when using iOS cells.
(I am a teacher, so I see this kind of error frequently... don't worry..)

some Considerations:
1) NEVER add a label to a cell. Doing so, very time a cell is reused, previous  label stays here, and a new label is added

2) as label are transparent, you will see all text overlapped..

3) You are leaking memory, as no one will detach/ release labels.

so the way can be:

A)Simple for simple case
use TAGS, as Apple did on old days of cells..
(code i

make some defines:

```
let TEXT_TAG = 2000
```

add label if not present, if present get it vi TAG:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: REUSE, for: indexPath ) 

let text = "my text..."
    if let label = cell.viewWithTag(TEXT_TAG) as? UILabel{
        label.text = text
    }else{
        let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50)
        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        label.text = text
        cell.addSubview(label)
    }
```

B) make a custom cell...

```
class CustomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var label: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50)
        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
```

in controller simply:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: REUSE, 
      for: indexPath ) as! CustomViewCell

        cell.label = "my text"
```

Answer (score 0):

I get your problem,you get the cell from tableView reuseable pool.The first problem,if you want change UITableViewCell View,you need to creat a son class of it.I get a function to fix it.
I use Stackoverflow first time,I don't know where can I put my code,so I write it under this sentence.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
for let item in cell.contentView.subviews {
        item.removeFromSuperView();
    }
```

And then using your code,it should help you.

Comment: You can make a sun class of UITableViewCell ,then use it to creat cell.